# Using named arguments as variables

Tags: python, django

I am using django but I think this question primarily belongs to Python itself.

I have something like:

```
def get(self, request, arg, *args, **kwargs):

    if kwargs['m0'] == 'death':
      if kwargs['m1'] == 'year':
         result = Artists.objects.filter(death_year=arg)
      elif kwargs['m1'] == 'month':
         result = Artists.objects.filter(death_month=arg)
      elif kwargs['m1'] == 'day':
         result = Artists.objects.filter(death_day=arg)
    elif kwargs['m0'] == 'birth':
      if kwargs['m1'] == 'year':
         result = Artists.objects.filter(birth_year=arg)
      elif kwargs['m1'] == 'month':
         result = Artists.objects.filter(birth_month=arg)
      elif kwargs['m1'] == 'day':
         result = Artists.objects.filter(birthh_day=arg)
```

Where `death_year` is a named argument that is a  field in my model `Artists` representing a column in my database. The variables 'm0' and `m1` are passed from the `urlconf` to my get function (it is actually a `get` method in my view class).
Can I control the name value of the variable `death_year` without using an if else if chain (i.e. make it `death_month` or `birth_year`)? Since I have many choices, I will have to use a ridiculously very long conditional chain that leads to this same line but with just a different named argument.

I strongly doubt that you should understand this whole problem to answer the question. The original question is simple: Can I use a named argument and its corresponding value as variables in Python?

Comment: Do you have an example of what value `arg` has? `Model.objects.filter(**dic)` is perfectly valid where `dic = {'death_year': 'foo'}`

Comment: Thanks @Sayse, I actually tried that but I got `Exception Type: FieldError`
`Exception Value: Cannot parse keyword query as dict`

Comment: You should show what you tried then, as I said, its perfectly valid so it will be more of an issue with what `arg` is

Comment: `arg` can be string or integer.

Comment: Can you post a bit longer example? In this situation it's easier to understand from code what you are trying to do.

Comment: It looks like `arg` is the *value* of the keyword argument then, its unclear how you expect to find out the name of the argument

Comment: Okay I will modify the post

Comment: Actually I can construct the key name from the extra arguments passed from `urlconf`

Comment: If you know your view is getting 'm0' and 'm1' arguments from the urlconf, why not give the function actual m0 and m1 arguments instead of using **kwargs? Makes for easier reading..

Comment: Because I don't want to directly access the database while not sure if these really are valid strings. If I check if these arguments from the user I really valid I will need to match them from the database.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From what I can make out you can construct the key and then pass in an arg to construct the dict, then include that in the filter

```
key = '%s_%s' % (kwargs['m0'], kwargs['m1'])
result = Artists.objects.filter(**{key: arg})
```

Comment: `{key, arg}` or `{key: arg}` ?

Comment: Awesome! Thanks a zillion times!

Comment: @itzmeontv - Thanks! Ejonas, no worries enjoy

Comment: The gory details (which was far too hard to find in the usual places): https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#index-36

Answer (score 1):

The basic and incredibly powerful idea in Python is that you can pass a list of positional arguments without writing `args[0], args[1],...` and/or a dict of keyword arguments without writing `foo=kwargs["foo"], bar=kwargs["bar"],...` by using `*` and `**` as in `func( *args, **kwargs)`

A function can likewise be written to accept a list of positional args of arbitrary length, and any set of unmatched keyword arguments: `def func( a, b, c=0, *args, **kwargs)`. (`args` and `kwargs` are not reserved words, just conventional variable names)

This example probably shows most of it in operation:

```
>>> def foo( a, b=0, c=0, *args, **kwargs):
...   print( "a,b,c: ", a, b, c)
...   print( args)
...   print( kwargs)
... 
>>> foo( *[1,2,3,4], **{"baz":42} )
a,b,c:  1 2 3
(4,)
{'baz': 42}

>>> foo( 1, b=2,  **{"baz":42, "c":3} )
a,b,c:  1 2 3
()
{'baz': 42}

>>> foo( **{"baz":42, "c":3, "a":1, "zork":"?" } )
a,b,c:  1 0 3
()
{'zork': '?', 'baz': 42}
```

kwargs is a dict so if you want, you can use `kwargs.keys()` and all the other `dict` methods to introspect what the user actually passed and validate, parse, process etc. Django frequently uses `kwargs.pop()` to allow the fetching of arguments for the current function, while leaving other named arguments to propagate down a possibly deep set of nested function invocations until a routine near the bottom finds an optional keyword argument of its own.

Comment: Thank you! My problem actually that was I didn't put ** before my dict variable. Thanks for your detailed answer!

Comment: @nigel222 In the keyword arguments of your example call `foo( 1, b=2,  **{"baz":42, "c":3} )`, the key "c" becomes a **variable** whereas "baz" remains as a **key** for the dictionary kwargs. It doesn't know its type until it is parsed? A dynamically typed language?

Comment: @Leon_Chang Yes, Python is strongly but dynamically typed. But no, the example is exactly equivalent to `foo( 1, b=2, c=3, baz=42)` and what is happening is name-binding, not "becoming a variable". In the function, the name `c` is bound to the object `3` (type int, immutable), and `kwargs['baz']` is bound to `42`.  A Python assignment doesn't copy, but if the RHS is an expression, it may be binding the name to a new object (like 47.3*foo, a newly computed float) or to an existing one (like z=x.y, where an attribute y of x is already bound to an object and z is now bound to that same object).

Comment: @nigel222 Thanks! But how is it so smart to know that c should be bound to 3 instead of `kwargs['c']` bound to 3? I initially thought that c would get default 0. In which case, c is bound to 0 and kwargs['c'] is bound to 3, anything wrong with that? Also, can we think name as an address pointer in C or reference in C# since I can print out their addresses with `hex(id(47.3*foo(1,2))) or hex(id(z))`?

Comment: @Leon_Chang by the function signature `foo( a, b=0, c=0, *args, **kwargs)`. `c` is defined as an argument, `baz` is not so it gets swept up into kwargs.